# How do the team boosts work?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

There are some tech stations around town that activate a team boost for three BluGlo. I've found health, building, and speed boosts. Do they always work for two minutes, and what exactly is the perk? Does health regenerate or building cost less? How much faster is the speed?

Comment: Using the team boosts is widely considered a waste of time (and bluglo) by most players. The bonus you get is so minor and lasts such a short amount of time, it's not really worth gathering the resources needed to get the buff.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you exact details on their percentage boosts but each tower provides a boost to your entire team when you deposit the BluGlo. Health increases your health regen, movement speed boosts how fast you run, building boosts how quickly you build things etc, they're fairly self-explanatory.

For the most part they lasted for 2 minutes as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

- Health pylon: increases HP by 20%
- Shield pylon: increases Shield by 20%
- Movement pylon: increases movement speed by 20%
- Stamina pylon: increase max Stamina by 20%
- Building pylon: increases Build Speed by 100%